# Steganography of JFIF file

Tags: cryptography, hex, ascii, jpeg, steganography

In cyber security competition, there was one single question about steganography, which was only solved by two teams, but the solution was not published afterwards.

Considering that i have very little experience in steganography and cryptography, I was interested to solve that problem. Unfortunately, i still find it a little difficult to solve by now.

Before mentioning solutions that i have utilized, I will show the task (description of the task is purely for example, and was made up in the competition):

> Cert agents found out conversations of two hackers, and tried to review it in order to get password of their server. Unfortunately, hackers didn't write their password anywhere in open format. Although, on mail, this weird picture was attached. Can you find out server's password with utilization of attached image?

[Click here for image](https://i.cubeupload.com/aOnubk.jpg).

To check the hidden messages in picture, I got it's source, and for better understanding, encoded it in hex.

This is how normal source of JFIF looked:

```
ÿØÿà^@^PJFIF^@^A^B^@^@^A^@^A^@^@ÿí^@<84>Photoshop 3.0^@8BIM^D^D^@^@^@^@^@g^\^B(^@bFBMD01000a820d0000ec2d0000a3640000076a0000616d0000e6b000005f260100362e0100853a0100d342010079070200^@ÿâ^KøICC_PROFILE^@^A^A^@^@^Kè^@^@^@^@^B^@^@^@mntrRGB XYZ ^GÙ^@^C^@^[^@^U^@$^@^_acsp^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@öÖ^@^A^@^@^@^@Ó-^@^@^@^@)ø=Þ¯òU®xBúäÊ<83>9^M^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^Pdesc^@^@^AD^@^@^@ybXYZ^@^@^AÀ^@^@^@^TbTRC^@^@^AÔ^@^@^H^Ldmdd^@^@       à^@^@^@<88>gXYZ^@^@
h^@^@^@^TgTRC^@^@^AÔ^@^@^H^Llumi^@^@
|^@^@^@^Tmeas^@^@
<90>^@^@^@$bkpt^@^@
´^@^@^@^TrXYZ^@^@
È^@^@^@^TrTRC^@^@^AÔ^@^@^H^Ltech^@^@
Ü^@^@^@^Lvued^@^@
è^@^@^@<87>wtpt^@^@^Kp^@^@^@^Tcprt^@^@^K<84>^@^@^@7chad^@^@^K¼^@^@^@,desc^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^_sRGB IEC61966-2-1 black scaled^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@XYZ ^@^@^@^@^@^@$ ^@^@^O<84>^@^@¶Ïcurv^@^@^@^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^@^E^@
```

Which gave me some information:

1. In hexadecimal format, JFIF files always start with `FFD8`, therefore i was sure that it was JFIF file.
2. Approximately at offset of 10, we can conclude that Photoshop was used for the picture.
3. Finally, little after line with the `Photoshop 3.0.8BIM`, There was an hexadecimal string (01000a820d0000ec2d0000a3640000076a0000616d0000e6b000005f260100362e0100853a0100d342010079070200), although it didn't became hexadecimal when i encoded it, it was hexadecimal before, so i tried to decode it from hex, but i couldn't encode it to UTF-8, since bytes it contained was not in ordinal. So i got this byte array:

`\x01\x00\n\x82\r\x00\x00\xec-\x00\x00\xa3d\x00\x00\x07j\x00\x00am\x00\x00\xe6\xb0\x00\x00_&\x01\x006.\x01\x00\x85:\x01\x00\xd3B\x01\x00y\x07\x02\x00`.

I also couldn't find image markers such as SOI (`FFh D8h`), APP0 (`FFh E0h`). Maybe, there's code for some file hidden after end of JFIF file code.

What could be the main clue to this picture? I'm not trying to directly ask for the solution unless it's enjoyable, but am i doing something incorrectly? The only approximate clue i have found was the hexadecimal string (`01000a820d0000ec2d0000a3640000076a0000616d0000e6b000005f260100362e0100853a0100d342010079070200`) which i couldn't decode.

## Main Question

So shortly, what could be the best method to find the hidden message of JFIF?

Thanks a lot for reading!

Comment: If you're trying to solve, or get a hint about a puzzle, the question is more suitable for [Puzzling SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/). It doesn't seem like you have a programming question per se, which is what we deal with here.

Comment: It's true that i'm trying to solve the task, But in this case i'm looking for proper method to solve the task which would indeed involve utilization of programming. Thanks a lot for suggestion @Reti43

Comment: Just because you want to use some code, it doesn't mean your question is a good fit for this site. If you were asking *"how to convert 'a' thing to 'b' thing"*, that'd be a specific question. But asking *"how to find something hidden and I don't know what the right extraction method is"* is too broad.

Comment: @Reti43 Well, thank you for opinion, but i have written many specifications in the question that don't make it broad.

Comment: You have written a lot of specifications about what you've done so far and what you think the solution might be. However, "*Maybe, there's code for some file hidden after end of JFIF file code.*", "*What could be the main clue to this picture?*", and "*The only approximate clue i have found was the hexadecimal string*" don't inspire a lot of specificity. Anyway, I have indeed stated my opinion and if others in the community agree with that, they'll let you know.